# Json object reflection

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to figure out how I can get a property value from a jsonObject by giving a property name

well, let's say I have the object

```
var jsonObj = eval('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}');
```

and I want to get a value by using a method

```
function getPropertyValue(key){
 return jsonObj.key;
}

alert(getPropertyValue("key1"));
```

I know that I can get the value by using *jsonObj.Key* but I want to do it by use a method

Is it possible?

Comment: You shouldn't use plain `eval()` to parse json. Use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) (needed for older browsers, in modern browsers it doesn't do anything and the native JSON support will be used) and then `JSON.parse('...')` instead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one: Parse your JSON using the correct methods and avoid using `eval`:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse( '[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]' );
```

And your method can look like this:

```
function getPropertyValue(key){
 return jsonObj[ key ];
}
```

Comment: well, the problem was the eval. By using the JSON.parse the problem solved. Thanks Sirko

Answer (score 0):

You can access objects like arrays:

```
return jsonObj[key];
```

Comment: The problem was the eval. I tried it with JSON.parse and the problem solved. Thanks for answering

Comment: Don't use eval for that, I've make jsfiddle demo for you http://jsfiddle.net/aPBFh/

Comment: I need the eval cause I am getting the json as a string from server side. So the dom recognizes it as a string and not as an object. That's why I need the eval (or better the JSON.parse)

Answer (score 0):

If jsonObj.key works, you can parameterize the key thusly:

```
 function getPropertyValue(key)
 {  
    return jsonObj[key];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getPropertyValue(key){
 return jsonObj[key];
}

alert(getPropertyValue("key1")); //will alert value1
```